# SQL query to select groups in groups

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello I am unable to figure out the way for writing SQL query for following table and scenario

Lets say we have following table viz. LowestBid

```
ItemID      SuppplierID  LowestBid

A1                 S1               10
A1                 S2               20
A1                 S3               30
B1                 S2               10
B1                 S3               20
C1                 S3               10
C1                 S1               20
C1                 S2               30
```

Lets say we have a function which has parameter viz. N , the out put of intended SQL query is like e.g. N=1.
 For N=1, we need to find one supplier for each item whose bid value is lowest for the same item.

```
ItemID      SuppplierID  LowestBid

A1                 S1               10
B1                 S2               10
C1                 S3               10
```

If N=2
 For N=2, we need to find one suppliers for each item whose bid value is lowest and second lowest bid value for the same item.

```
ItemID      SuppplierID  LowestBid

A1                 S1               10
A1                 S2               20
B1                 S2               10
B1                 S3               20
C1                 S3               10
C1                 S1               20
```

Comment: To be clear, you want the lowest N bids per Item?

Comment: Which DBMS you're using?

Comment: @JoshSmeaton Yes, you are right.

Comment: @DirkNM I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 for my project.

Comment: Well, in this case the answer from @JoshSmeaton should do it.

Comment: @DirkNM Yes, the answer from Josh Smeaton  works, after looking his solution I realized that I need practice to improve my skill, will you please suggest resources for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using postgres or another rdbms that has analytic/window functions, you can use [row_number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734(v=sql.100).aspx) to filter for the rows you're interested in:

```
select
  q.item_id,
  q.supplier_id,
  q.bid
from (
select
  item_id,
  supplier_id,
  bid,
  row_number() over (partition by item_id order by bid) as row_num
from bids) q
where q.row_num <= 2 -- N=2;
```

Produces:

```
ITEM_ID SUPPLIER_ID BID
1       1           10
1       2           20
2       3           10
2       1           20
3       2           10
3       3           20
```

See the fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ce3a1/1

Comment: It works and solved my problem. Thanks a lot. Can you please suggest me, how can I improve my skill to write SQL queries.

Comment: @maheshcs just lots of practise. If you're fairly confident with regular queries and aggregates, look into analytic queries and window functions for some more advanced stuff.